# All USB ports stop working after connect specific network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb

using windows 7 , Hp Probook 4520s. When i connect to wifi at work, after 5 -10 mins (sometimes more longer than that) all my usb ports stop working, i unplug and plug again my mouse, printer and etc, but no success. Until i restart computer, dont work. Also i cant properly shut down computer after this issue. And having this problem only when i connect wifi at work. At home or other places just works well. It's about 1 week that I'm facing this problem. there was no such problem before. Note that my co-workers using same OS and computer with me but they dont have such problem.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: sounds like you have somehow enabled location based profiles, this one recognizes your wireless LAN at work and goes into some energy saving mode. if you installed additional software for your wireless card, check there.

Comment: I prefer to write shots into the dark as comments ;) glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comments this is most likely due to location based profiles that distingiush between different places (like work and home) by the wifi(s) you have in reach.

The additional software that controls your wifi probably activates some sort of energy saving mode that disables certain features of your laptop.